# Flux and TYPO3 6.2.7 / 6.2.9

Tags: typo3, flux

I tried the latest versions of flux in a fresh TYPO3 Instalaton 6.2.7 and 6.2.9.
I used the same templates for fluidcontent and fluidpages and it dont work properly.

The Page Grids dont work. (The default TYPO3 Grids are shown)
And the grids in the content elements dont work too.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If it shows the default TYPO3 columns, you probably did not select the fluidpages backend layout in the page record. In recent fedext/TYPO3 versions, you need to edit the properties of your root page and set both "Backend Layout (this page only)" and "Backend Layout (subpages of this page)" to "Fluidpages" in the "Appearance" tab